# Does the word "commute" apply only to work?

Tags: word-usage

The title is the question.

We usually say something like "my commute takes an hour", because the commute being "*to work*" is implicit.

But is it required? Or I can say "I read a book on my bi-weekly commute to the gym"?

If I can't, is there a more appropriate word?

I found several instances of "commute" being used in this and other contexts, but every definition I found (admittedly on a relatively short research) is quite explicit in that it's a travel *between home and work*, so I was wondering whether "commute to the gym" is actually correct or if it is an abuse of language (such as "I only perused the book" meaning the exact opposite of what was intended, or "irregardless" being just plain wrong).

Comment: It can apply to any regular to-from transposition, but will be assumed to imply attending to a job if context does not imply otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate some initial research effort. For example, there are hundreds of thousands of web search results for *commute to the gym*, and millions for *commute to school*, plus many dictionary definitions of *commute* do not mention work. If you attempted this kind of research and it was not adequate, you must explain why. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster, thank you for the warm welcome! This is my first post on EL&U but I'm not new to SE -- I just didn't login. Regarding my post, I did search and found several instances of "commute" being used in this and other contexts, but every definition I found (admittedly on a relatively short research) is quite explicit in that it's a travel *between home and work*, so I was wondering whether "commute to the gym" is actually correct or if it is an abuse of language (such as "I only perused the book" meaning the exact opposite of what was intended, or "irregardless" being just plain wrong).

Comment: Nevertheless, I updated the question with my comment.

Comment: @HotLicks, that is how I have it in mind, but is it really correct? Is there a dictionary out there defining it this way?

Comment: The first dictionary I consulted [defines commute](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/commute) as "to travel regularly over some distance, as from a suburb into a city and back". It mentions work in its example, but not in the actual definition. Merriam-Webster gives a similar definition, mentioning work only in its example. So now you have both real world usage and dictionary definitions supporting a commute to somewhere other than work.

Comment: @KannE that's interesting, thanks! English is not my native language, so my knowledge of the word "peruse" comes mostly from seeing its meaning being corrected every time someone dares to use it. The grammar police turns out to be wrong, it seems.

Comment: @nnnnnn okay, that's a good definition. My research was googling "commute definition" and opening each page from the search results, since I don't own a physical english dictionary. Literally every link in the first page (for me) defines it as either "travel between home and work" or "change (a prison sentence or other penalty) to a less severe one", though I must have missed the definitions you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it means *especially* to work, but not exclusively to work.

Consider https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commuting :

> to travel back and forth regularly (as between a suburb and a city)

It is fairly easy to use the word for other, non-work vocational commutes, such as in the common term *commuter school* for a college or university that mostly services folks living in an area (rather than students who move to the campus). It would be trickier to use for other trips, but is permissible.

*Trip* is easier to use. Context can make it clear that it is recurring.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear now! But the concept of a "commuter school" (or, more precisely, a non-commuter one) is foreign to me; I always commuted from home to college, as did most of my friends. "moving to the campus" is movie stuff for us :-)